# html2pdf sort table before output

Tags: php, jquery, html2pdf

I'm creating a table with php with data from two different sql tables.
My output is like this:

```
19.01.2016 text text2
17.02.2016 text text2
08.02.2016 text text2
```

I need to order the table by date before it's outputted by the html2pdf class. I tried to load the table using jquery and put it into a div, but it's outputted before i can load the content from another site.

Any hints how to do it?

Comment: I assume(?) you store the data in a array? Then you can sort it by value. Show us the PHP

Comment: Oh well I think this could be a solution. Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to isnisn.

After storing the data in a multidimensional array und sorting it by the date value i was able to create the correct table.